# Installing package with Nuget in .NET core on mac

Tags: macos, json.net, nuget, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm using .NET core on a mac with Visual Studio Code. i'm trying to install NewtonSoft.Json to use as a Json parser. The command I use is:

```
nuget install CoreCompat.NewtonSoft.Json -Pre
```

I use this command in my top level project folder. This leaves me with two problems. Firstly, and most glaring, I am still not able to use the package in my code.

```
using NewtonSoft.Json;
```

will not compile. Secondly, although this does download the package, it downloads a whole bunch of other stuff too - files like System.Threading, and puts them in my project directory. There are about 40 of these extra files. I already have these dependencies (which I'm assuming they must be) in my .nuget folder (and I'm able to include them in any project). I don't want to clutter up my project folder. How do I properly use nuget to install this package?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command you want is

```
dotnet add package NewtonSoft.Json
```

This will add the following to your csproj file, which you could also do manually.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NewtonSoft.Json" Version="10.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then you can use `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build` and friends to continue developing.

I also believe that you didn't mean to use the `CoreCompat.` prefixed package as this is not the original JSON.net library.